# C++ declare zoned_time for 1 PM today east coast time

Tags: c++, timezone, c++-chrono

I'm looking for how to declare a time for a configurable number of minutes before 1 pm east coast time on the day of running the program. I've found ways to get a fixed time of the timezone such as:

`chrono::zoned_time onePmEastCoastTime ("New York/New York", chrono::sys_days{ 2022y / chrono::April/ 15d } + 13h );`

How can I declare a configurable time that will match a specific timezone?

Comment: `onePmEastCoastTime - std::chrono::minutes(mins)` where `mins` is an integer with the number of minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to specify the time in terms of local time as opposed to UTC.  The key to this is in the use of `local_days` vs `sys_days`.

`sys_days` is a count of days in UTC.

`local_days` is a count of days in some local time that can be subsequently paired with a `timezone`.

Maybe you are looking for:

```
chrono::minutes m = ...
chrono::zoned_time onePmEastCoastTime{"America/New_York",
      chrono::local_days{ 2022y / chrono::April/ 15d } + 13h - m};
```

Comment: Thanks!  Or `m` could be negative.  I've fixed my answer per your suggestion though.

Comment: Thank you Howard. I have one more question. How can I get local_days constructor using now()? I'm getting errors from using: ```chrono::local_days{ floor<chrono::days>(chrono::system_clock::now()) };```

Comment: The current local date in New York is `floor<days>(zoned_time{"America/New_York", system_clock::now()}.get_local_time())`.  I.e. first get the local time in the desired time zone, and _then_ floor it to days.